# OCT configuration of Outlook 2013 with Exchange 2013

Tags: configuration, exchange-2013, outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013

We have Outlook 2013 configured using the Office Customization Tool (setup.exe /admin) that is built into Office 2013 enterprise.  This configuration worked great with Exchange 2007 but just fixing the server address in the configuration results in Outlook 2013 saying that it cannot communicate with the server followed by the OCT file not being correct.  If we do not configure the OCT settings, it runs through the Welcome wizard and auto configures correctly.  How can I fix the OCT config to make the profile without asking questions?

This is the original post [Issue creating Exchange 2013 Default Profile using Office Customization Tool](https://serverfault.com/questions/590426/issue-creating-exchange-2013-default-profile-using-office-customization-tool) that I wanted to ask clarification on because the answer doesn't tell you how to fix the problem.  It was deleted by server fault moderators because it doesn't "answer the question". I was told that what comments are for, but I don't have enough rep to comment.  Not a great way to encourage new users to your forum...

Comment: [SF] is **not a forum** Those are canned messages. We get too many forum-style posts to write custom messages to everyone who can't be bothered to read the help messages on the site. See the [help] for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your environment is like ours, Outlook will auto configure itself properly if you do not customize it with the Office Customization Tool.  There is a 5 step wizard where you mostly just click next until you are done.  If that is the case, you want to reset the Outlook customization done by the OCT.  You can do this by deleting the file c:\program files\Microsoft Office\custom15.prf  or custom14.prf.  That will restore the 5 step wizard that works.

We employed computer side group policy preferences to delete the file when the computers boot up.

To suppress the wizard and let Outlook open without asking questions, we set a user side group policy.  This requires the ADMX templates for Office 2010/2013 to be downloaded and added to your GP console.  User->Admin Templates->Outlook 2013->Account Settings->Exchange-> Automatically configure based on Active Directory Primary SMTP address.